# GIF files skipping frames in PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animated-gif

I have a strange issue. I made a few animated GIFs in Photoshop and later on I wanted to import them into a PowerPoint presentation. So far so good, but when I ran the presentation, some frames were missing or not in place.

Why is that? I have the same issue with every GIF I created.

Here's [an example of a GIF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIetZ.gif) which loses frames in PowerPoint but shows without errors in browsers.

Comment: For the future, please stop posting the same question across the network, but only post it *once*. Thank you!

Comment: If the gif plays at all, it's not a linking issue.  Have you inserted the GIFs using PPT's insert picture command (as opposed to inserting them as an object)?  I tried the file here in PPT 2003 and 2007; seems to work fine on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Are the .gif files in the same directory as the PowerPoint presentation? If you're working in Windows and you move the PowerPoint file after you've linked the files you may have issues - Windows doesn't do well with relative links.

2) Are the .gif files embedded or just linked? You may want to try embedding them into the file - you'll end up with a bigger PowerPoint file, but it may fix this.

3) How large are the file sizes? Remember, PowerPoint has to try and load each file as you enter the frame.

4) It sounds like you're running this on a laptop - have you tried looking at the presentation on a desktop? Check the system you're working on for RAM, processor speed, etc. to make sure you have enough horsepower to drive this.

5) It used to be that you needed at least 100M continuous space on the hard drive to run video files (so Windows could cache). I'm not sure if there's a similar requirement for .gifs but if it runs fine on another machine and not so well on your laptop you may wish to defragment your hard drive (if you're running on Windows).

Do you really need animated .gifs? Sometimes you do - I've used them effectively to demonstrate mechanical concepts, but the example you gave us, while nice looking, doesn't seem to do anything but demonstrate that you can have motion in a presentation. Remember that PowerPoint audience members are like deer - they'll immediately focus on motion to the exclusion of anything else - not helpful if you're trying to get them to pay attention to things like bullet points that say "Under no circumstances should you ever, ever push the shiny red 'Self-Destruct' switch on the Doomsday device". Seriously consider how important the animated .gifs are before tossing them in. I am even fairly conservative with transitions since I want people focusing on the bullet points, not the animations.

Comment: number 4 and 5 are not related to my issue for sure (using PC i7 950, 12GB DDR3  with  SSD on SATA3) ... files are large compared to most of the gifs I used before (can it be the reason that im scaling down the gifs?) ... 
EDIT:
It's not in the same directory  and I have no idea about the 2nd question :P ... 

it has to be gif file as my Tutor requires it to be gif file... It's for uni and I will put my hand drew animations in there

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not have Photoshop... I ran into the same problem using gifsicle.  The gifs work fine in most programs but in powerpoint there are frames missing in some of them.

The solution was to invoke "careful" command in gifsicle, which they say "Writes slightly larger GIFs that avoid bugs in some other GIF implementations. Some Java and Internet Explorer versions cannot display the correct, minimal GIFs that Gifsicle produces. Use the --careful option if you are having problems with a particular image."

http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html

Like this
gifsicle --careful --delay 50 v1.gif > v2.gif